# What happens to an img html tag with a json src?

Tags: html, cors, cross-domain

What happens to an img html tag (`<img src="address-to-server-action">`)  if the response from the server is not a valid img, say JSON. Would the browser throw a parse error? Does all browsers have the same behaviour? Does it matter if the img is hidden?

I'm actually just trying to bring a cookie from a cross domain server that serves only JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try something like `<img src="http://example.com/some.json">` and want JSON back from it is that browsers won’t let you. If the `src` value isn’t a valid image the browser supports, it’s just not going to show it and not let you do anything else with the response.

That’s how browsers work and that behavior [is documented in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#image-request), which references [the request algorithm in the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request), one property of which is the request [mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode).

Unless a fetch is performed with a specific mode set, then the default mode `no-cors` is used. And [the HTML spec algorithm for image requests](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#image-request) doesn’t set any other mode, so they’re `no-cors`.

And responses to `no-cors` requests are handled by browsers as [opaque filtered responses](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque), which means that from any client-side JavaScript code you might try in your web app, you won’t be able to access any information/properties from the response.

Comment: Even thought the browser won't let me access the response, the cookie is still been set by the browser, so this is exactly what I need. Do you know if there is any standard that ensures the cookie will be set? and one more question, I've tried 3 different browsers, and all of them don't show error when the image parsing fails just a placeholder instead of the image (which is great); do you know if there is any standard for that?

Comment: As far as the browser requirements when an image is broken, see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#updating-the-image-data:img-error-7, which says an event named `error` gets fired at the `img` element. The spec doesn’t state requirements for what browsers must do for an `img` element that receives an `error` event (though your app code could set an event listener that does something with it), but at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-img-element:attr-img-alt-3 the spec has some “User agents may provide the user…” cases for what do when an image is broken. None of those say to show the user an error

Answer (score 0):

The browser will display alternative text. The browser may inform the user that the image is not properly loaded.

You can hide the image (display: none;) and it will not show up.

You can set cross domain cookies as described in http://www.ainixon.me/set-cookie-on-cross-domains/.